# How can I use yield :content before content_for in Rails templates?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to use `yield`/`content_for` in `<head>`, but assign the value in `<body>`. I have found that this works fine when the value is being assigned from within a template that is being `yield`ed to, but not one that is being `render`ed. Templates that are being `render`ed are compiled after `<head`>, so my value is already set in stone. Is there a way to achieve what I am trying to do?

I tried making application.html.erb look like this:

```
<%= render layout: 'application_template' do %>
  <!-- <body> content here -->
<% end %>
```

and `_application_template.html.erb` look like:

```
<!doctype>
<html>
  <head>
    <%= content_for :my_value %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= yield %>
  </body
</html>
```

but the same problem happens, the value is nil when `_application_template.html.erb` is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do the following.
In your head check if there is any content to yield and yield it if it is.

```
    <% if content_for?(:my_value) %>
      <%= yield :my_value %>
    <% else %>
```

And then define your content somewhere in your body.

```
    <% content_for :my_value do %>
      # your contents
    <% end %>
```

Comment: That's what I already do. I needed the `yield` to be lazily evaluated, or something similar. I came up with a solution, but thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a solution.

```
# layouts/application.html.erb

<% content_for(:body_content) { render partial: 'layouts/body_content' } %>

<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <%= yield :my_value if content_for?(:my_value) %>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= yield :body_content %>
  </body>
</html>
```

and

```
# layouts/_body_content.html.erb

# everything that used to be in <body></body> goes here and is maintained here.
```

This makes sure that all of the `#content_for` calls I need to happen will happen before `<head>` is compiled in my layout. It is also easier to maintain than some of the other hacks I had thought of trying.